# What is the significance of the new text on the buttons of the Flag Dismissal dialog?

Tags: support, flags, moderator-tools

```
Old Text          New Text
--------          --------
Valid             Helpful
Invalid           Declined
```

Is this a cosmetic change, or is there a subtle (or not so subtle) policy change that goes along with this?

Comment: If this is supposed to help curb the tide of meta questions, it's not going to work. "Declined" will still prompt people to inquire why their flag was "declined" even though the action they suggested was clearly taken on the question. From my experience, that's what the majority of the meta questions are about. I like "Helpful", though. It seems more descriptive and accurate than "Valid".

Comment: Mmmmm, I like "declined" rather than "invalid."  Means more flag weights are going to get the beatdown.  Mmmm, beaten flag weights.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The names were changed to more accurately reflect the intent of each flag dismissal state.

> #### Helpful
>
> The flag was helpful in some way, even if the moderator did not agree with it or take any specific action as a result of it.

and

> #### Declined
>
> The moderator can't see any utility in this particular flag and therefore declined to act on it.

Comment: Should the "Invalid flag" flag still be called that?