# Could the meaning of helpful/declined be used as the title, instead of time on the flag summary page?

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-history

Currently, the flag weight summary shows the time and the words `helpful` and `Declined` next to your flags, after they have been processed.

When you hover over the time, it gives you the exact time (as elsewhere), which is great.
When you hover over the word, it gives you, what I believe to be, the time it was processed.  However, this is not an exact time, so for flags processed yesterday, the hover time just says `yesterday`:

[image]

Rather than showing the time the flag was processed, could we instead show the meaning of the flag attribute, as [explained by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103987/what-is-the-significance-of-the-new-text-on-the-buttons-of-the-flag-dismissal-dia/104022#104022)

E.g. the title attribute for helpful would be:

> The flag was helpful in some way, even if the moderator did not agree
>   with it or take any specific action as a result of it.

I think this would help to bring clarification to users who are having trouble interpreting a decision on flags (and hopefully reduce the questions on Meta).