# Character limit in "Flag-decline reason"?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, moderator-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Length limit for the “other” field in the Decline Flag dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106665/length-limit-for-the-other-field-in-the-decline-flag-dialog)

Sometime recently a new feature was added to the moderator's dialogue in handling flags: now when moderators decline a flag, we are invited to give a reason. We can choose from several built-in options, or give an "Other reason" using a text-field.

**Question:** is there a character limit on what can be input in that text-field?

I ask because just now I tried to give a slightly long (four sentences) reason for declining a user's flag. Clicking on the "decline" button after typing that reason gave no response. Only through guess work (since that symptom is similar to when the SE software refusing to let me submit too-long comments) did I figure out that significantly reducing the number of words in that reason allowed me to click the decline button.

**Suggestion:** If there is indeed a character limit, can a counter be displayed in the same way that it is available for comments?