# Is there a way to discuss a declined flag other than opening a question on Meta?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I understand that mods are very busy, and would not want to open up an avenue for endless back and forth over every flag.  However, when a flag is declined, is there a way to discuss it other than opening a question on Meta?  Or is that the preferred method?

I (obviously) have a specific flag in mind that was declined incorrectly, perhaps because I worded it improperly, and would like a chance to say so.  A question was closed as a duplicate of one that it simply is not, though it sounds similar.  Tellingly, the answer to the question it is marked as a duplicate of cannot work for the closed question. Where can I point that out?  Should I reflag it?

Comment: Hm? Why not just include the closed question here, so we can check it out and see if it's a duplicate or not? Meta is exactly where you should discuss this ;) But we need a bit more info.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to avoid that -- my question is more general: Should I post specific questions to Meta, or is there another recourse?

Comment: @Don: Yes, you can. In fact, we have an entire [meta-tag:specific-question] tag dedicated to questions about a specific question on SO.

Comment: @animuson: Thanks!  If you add that as an answer I can accept it.  I was unsure of the protocols and didn't see anything in the FAQ of either site.

Comment: @Don: If you want to ask a question about the flag and question, you should just edit that into your question here so we can take a look at it.

Comment: @Don why not just revamp this question and add a link to the flagged post. Otherwise this becomes a dupe of a faq post (i think).

Comment: Okay, you've all convinced me.  Since I didn't find the answer to this, I thought it was a good question to ask, but I must not have looked in the right place...

Comment: Just flag it again.  Three or more times is where it starts to get abusive.  If you've been shot down twice and you still don't know why, ask here.

Comment: **"The right thing for the user to do is to question the dismissal on meta..."** ([quote source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107216/when-should-the-not-an-answer-flag-be-used#comment275675_107229 "Wonder why nobody with authority did not yet posted that as an answer here? Is this a thing that should always be read between-the-lines? Is there some potential, possible damage that may happen some day in the future if (the horror!) this is stated here, loud and clear?"))

Answer (score 1):

[To my dismay as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252844/incorrect-wrong-duplicate-question/252846), there are currently no mechanisms to properly discuss flags, other than posting a [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) on Meta.

More at [Allow follow-up of declined flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144717/allow-follow-up-of-declined-flags).