# Should I flag an answer if it's incorrect?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should the “Not an Answer” flag be used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107216/when-should-the-not-an-answer-flag-be-used)

If there is a question with an answer that is clearly wrong and I have proof that it is incorrect should I flag the question or just down vote it?

Obviously I would provide the proof for the moderators to see it is clearly wrong if I flagged it so they'd know it was wrong.

Comment: If you do flag it, you have a 100% chance of it getting declined for the following reason: `flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than flagging it you should make a comment with the evidence and downvote it. This would not only save the moderators some time but more importantly(?) give the user the chance to edit the answer to make it a better fit. If others agree with you the post will receive more downvotes and the user is likely to remove it him/herself.

Or you can edit the answer yourself to fix minor mistakes in the answer.

Comment: Or edit it to fix what it wrong.

Comment: @ColeJohnson If the error is fundamentally wrong you shouldn't edit it.  (Just downvote and post a competing answer you feel is correct)  If their answer is generally correct, but just has a minor error then you could potentially fix that mistake (if it clearly was a mistake, not a point you disagree on) with an edit.

Answer (score 3):

Just downvote. Flags are not for marking correctness of an answer.