# NAA, or just bad answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/270230/1015495) basically boils down to "What is the difference between X and Y:"

> What is the difference between having
>   `<%# Eval("State") %>` in your aspx page or
>   `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "State") %>` in your aspx page?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13805517/1015495) boils down to "Yes, they are different:"

> I have seen following code
>       `<%# (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ApplicationId").ToString() == "-1" ? "N/A" : Eval("ApplicationId").ToString()) %>`
>   So I guess they slightly different.

So, I flagged NAA. Declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer. Okay. And I get that NAA flags are not meant for low-quality answers, or wrong answers...but I don't really see how this is an answer. If the question is "How are they different?" and the answer is "They are different", without any attempt to actually answer the question, can it really be considered an answer, even a really bad one?

> How are waffles and pancakes different?
>   I have seen them in different containers at the buffet. I guess they are different.

Comment: Reserve NAA to things that are not answers. A bad answer is an answer, non the less.

Comment: See [Either I need clarification on the 'Not an answer' flags or it needs a new description](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180247); same arguments apply.

Comment: Consider downvoting though, if you feel it's a very poor quality answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is actually pretty much a dupe of that question.  Shall we shut this down?

Comment: I still say that isn't an answer, though.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: If you feel this is a dupe of that one, then we vote on it. :-)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Would you say it's an *attempt at an answer*, albeit one that failed completely? If so, then don't flag with NAA, as that's meant for things which make no effort at all towards answering the question.

Comment: @Eso it's not an attempt. It completely missed the actual question. It should have been a comment.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: Then that's a failed attempt. Which is still an attempt.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn But where's the line between an attempt and "Which way to the railway station?" - "Tuesday!"?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn an attempt at what? because it's surely not an attempt to help the OP or to answer the question that was actually asked.