# Not An Answer Flag Declined - Don't See Why

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18965277/616443) as "Not an answer" because it fits the definition ("This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.")

The answer simply re-iterates the code the OP posted, then ends by saying "I think the problem is anywhere else, Please share your complete HTML and CSS code."

Does it make sense that the flag was declined?

Comment: Looks like a moot point now as the answer was deleted.

Answer (score 5):

Because it is an answer.

If you want a higher chance that your moderator flag might be actually acted upon, cast a custom moderator flag:

> This answer simply re-iterates the code the OP posted, then ends by saying "I think the problem is anywhere else, Please share your complete HTML and CSS code."

For "Not an Answer" flags, we're looking for questions posted as answers, comments posted as answers, "thanks," things like that.

Comment: "very low quality"?

Comment: "EDIT: FIXED. PROBLEM WAS THAT I HAD ADBLOCK PLUS ENABLED!" — The question ought to be nuked, me thinks...

Comment: I hear what your saying about the strict interpretation of "not an answer", but I did think that the ending with "I think the problem is anywhere else, Please share your complete HTML and CSS code." qualified.

Comment: @j08691 the keyword in the description is **attempt**.  The post was an attempt at an answer.  It was a poor quality answer and probably deserves to be deleted as VLQ or even a custom flag, but since it you selected Not an Answer, the mod had to judge the fact based on the type, not the post's quality.

Comment: You're being too strict, that answer is basically a comment posted as an answer. Neither flaggers nor moderators should judge answers based solely on its form.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I really don't see it as an attempt to answer at all. The poster simple reiterated the original code, said the problem is somewhere else, and requested more code. What part of that is an answer?

Comment: How is "*the code actually works, I think the problem is somewhere else*" an attempt at an answer?

Comment: @j08691 1) It led the person directly to solving the problem -- an environment issue -- rather than code. 2) It showed them exactly what the code was supposed to do. 3) It couldn't be properly formatted as a comment.

Comment: @user814064 I checked your code with the chrome in the JS fiddle it is appearing correctly here: http://jsfiddle.net/npsingh/FQtwc/show/ I think the problem is anywhere else, Please share your complete HTML and CSS code.

Comment: @j08691 it has been said before that "Yes" & "No" are acceptable answers.  They are bad answers on their own, but they are valid answers.  Similarly, a post that says "Your code works, here is the fiddle to prove it" is an answer in my opinion because it is telling the OP that there is nothing wrong.

Comment: @psubsee2003 In that case the question should be closed and not answered at all.

Comment: @WesleyMurch never said that the question shouldn't be closed.  I won't disagree with you there because it fits the old definition of too localized perfectly.  But it was certainly common practice (by some users) to answer a too localized post then vote to close.  I don't think the answer's quality changes rhat

Comment: @psubsee2003 So "works on my machine, post more code" really is a valid answer? I disagree. It's a perfect example of a useful comment though.

Comment: @WesleyMurch "valid answer" is a stretch, I would say a "valid attempt at an answer".  My whole point was the mods are being asked to be very strict on Not An Answer flags because that info is part of the review audit selection process.  I'd rather be forced to think about the type of flag I submit and get better quality review audits than the other way around.

Comment: It's obvious that the [NAA flag still needs clarification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180247/either-i-need-clarification-on-the-not-an-answer-flags-or-it-needs-a-new-descr/188092#188092)

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's an answer. The OP's problem was that the code didn't work for him. The answer very clearly states that the code does work.  In that regard, it's no different than other questions where the correct answer is to reject the premise the OP has cast.  This answer does that.

I declined the flag because it addresses the question and answers the issue (e.g., given what you've provided, your problem is somewhere else).

That having been said, the question itself is quite faulty, and I'm glad it was nuked from orbit.