# I think this should be a comment

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217508/gwt-uibinder-image-showing-but-not-resizing/4218167#4218167) because it is clearly a comment in my opinion, and not only in my opinion but in the answerer's opinion, too. (See his own comment below.)

So I don't understand why I got this for my flag: "*declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer*". This is not a wrong answer, this is not an answer. There's no other problem with it, probably it is a good comment.

Comment: Flagged it as what?

Comment: as not an answer

Comment: Obligatory flogging of my answer to the [NAA flag clarification request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180247/either-i-need-clarification-on-the-not-an-answer-flags-or-it-needs-a-new-descr/188092#188092).

Comment: @qben This looks perfectly like an answer to me.

Comment: You might want to look at [this comment from one of the mods on the dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag#comment566451_185074) The mods only see the title and part of the answer, so NAA flags won't work for this case

Comment: @SomeHelpfulCommenter thank you, I realized that. It's the most important conclusion for me in this case.

Answer (score 6):

The OP's comment didn't state that it should have been a comment, it says, "Regardless, this wasn't the OP's issue after all."  Just because it's not correct doesn't mean it's not an answer.  It's an incorrect answer, but still an *attempt to answer the question*.  As such, it's not "not an answer" and shouldn't be flagged.  It is appropriate for the mod to have declined the flag.

Since it's not the correct answer you can downvote the answer if you wish, since it may indeed be not useful.

Comment: I don't quite agree. I think he stated a general rule rather than answering the question.

Comment: @qben Regardless, he *thought* it was the answer.  He may have been wrong, and if he was, then you're free to downvote.  But he *thought* he was answering, and as such, it's not NAA.  Mods are not there to judge the technical merits of an answer, as per the decline message you were sent.  Just because it's wrong doesn't mean you should flag it.

Comment: OK, let's suppose he really thought that. Then you're right. It seemed to me that he didn't.

Comment: @qben Why would he say, "It's not the issue **after all**" if he knew from the start that it wasn't an answer.  The use of the phrase, "after all" implies that at one point in time he thought it was the problem, but realized later that it wasn't.

Comment: I didn't interpret his words this way. But from the people's votes here I see that it was me who misunderstood them... :)

Answer (score 3):

The post is clearly an answer.  The person is saying that the code segment should be `addStyleNames="{style.fortaImage}"` and not `styleName='{style.fortaImage}'` (the fact that he's pointing to the line `<g:Image styleName='{style.fortaImage}' resource='{res.fortaLogo}'/>` is somewhat confusing, but it's the only line which had the original text)