# Why was this "not an answer" flag declined when the answer is obviously a comment?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, link-only-answers, not-an-answer

I recently asked this question: [How to enable more than 2 finger support in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199416/how-to-enable-more-than-2-finger-support-in-chrome)

The question asked (tl;dr version):

> *Is it possible to instruct Chrome to listen to more than two simultaneous touch points with JavaScript (or some other means)? How?*

Which only merited one answer, very quickly after the question was asked.

The answer:

> Try to use HammerJS, it supports multitouch:
>
> http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/

This answer does not attempt to answer the question at all. It should have been a comment of something I might look into to try and resolve the issue. However, it does not answer the question of "Can Chrome does this? And how?" Additionally, it was a low-quality, link-only answer with no explanation or examples. It fails **two** pieces of criteria for a decent answer.

I flagged the question as "Not an answer" and it was declined. I believe strongly that the flag should have been accepted and the answer removed. Please advise.

Comment: It might be a bad (and low quality) answer, but it's an answer. "How to enable multitouch? Use hammer.js"

Comment: [When should the "Not an Answer" flag be used?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107216)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure how this is not an answer:

The user asks how to get Chrome to support multi-touch. The answer the user gave is to use a library that supports multi-touch.

That's an answer.

It could be improved with usage examples tailored to the asker, but otherwise it is a valid answer.  Whether or not it should be downvoted is up to you, but *it is an answer*.

The OP did edit his question to say that HammerTouch doesn't do what he needs it to do, so it's definitely a valid play to downvote the answer.

Comment: I guess I was under the impression that "Not an answer" also covered answers that are completely off-topic to the question. In the case I provided, there is absolutely no attempt to answer the actual question. They way that BaBL86 answered the question would make me think the question was asking for a resource, tool, or off-site reference, which bothers me more as that was not what I asked.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen Sometimes the answer to your question is an off-site tool or resource. We don't mind if that's the answer, we mind when that's the focus of the question. In your case, your question is a great example of a well written question that could conceivably have valid off-site resources as answers.

Comment: I just noticed today that the answer that I was asking about was deleted. However, my flag is still in a "declined" state and counting against me. Can that flag be changed to "helpful" since it obviously was? Or am I worrying about something that really holds no merit?

Answer (score 3):

That's not obviously not an answer. It looks like an attempt to answer. Not a very good one, to be sure, and is probably not answering the question asked. It should be voted on accordingly.

But "Not an answer" flags should be for things that aren't even an attempt to answer.

- I'm having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?
- Dude, that's awesome.
- I have a similar issue. It's ...
- Thanks! This helped

"Answers" like that aren't attempting to answer *any* question, much less the one that has been asked. Save your NAA flags for those.